# Android: app installed on real device can't connect to internet

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api

My React Native 0.70.1 app runs well on android simulator, however when it is installed on real device (not formally published apk, have to allow installation on real device), it can't connect to the internet and thus failed. Here is the fetch method:

```
 let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/viewers/signup`;  //<<==url is https://...
      //console.log("Signup post URL : ", url);
      let obj = JSON.stringify({
        _device_id: device_id,
        cell: cell,
        country_code: country_code,
        name: username,
      });
      console.log("obj : ", obj);
      let res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
        },
          body: obj,
        });
```

Here `url` is `https`. I remember someone was having the similar issue before but could not recall the cause and solution.

Comment: Did you request the permissions for that? Or do you have any error message?

Comment: Are you running debug build on an android phone?

Comment: Hi `Thomas Meinhart`, when installing the apk downloaded, the device prompted it is unsafe app and do you want to continue (install anyway). There is no error on real device.

Comment: hi `Vasyl Nahuliak`, the apk package was generated with ./gradlew assembleRelease and under `/android/app/build/outputs/apk`. How to tell if it is debug version?

Comment: It is the latest build and there was no encounter of such issue with provious build. Not aware of change which may cause the issue.

Comment: It turns out that a connection rule is too strict on real device.